# Request header in HttpGet

Tags: android, json, http-get

There is API [here](https://openexchangerates.org/documentation) that sends JSON of exchange rates and I got it via `HttpGet`from [url](http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID) with my account `ID` parameter, but to clarify whether it has changed, I'm suppose to send (request headers  from previous request`ETag` and `Date` ) `If-None-Match` and `If-Modified-Since` with appropriate values, respectively. I did as follows:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(encodeUrl);
httpGet.addHeader("If-None-Match", "ETag recieved from previos request");
httpGet.addHeader("If-Modified-Since", "Tue, 21 Jan 2014 14:55:25 GMT");
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

In case, if there were alters it sends me again whole JSON with rates, but if it had not it's suppose to send `304 – Not Modified`. I've tryied above code but every time I got whole JSON, whereas `it has  not changed`! Did anybody encounter such an issue? Or I've missed anything?
Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you have "ID" hardcoded. It is supposed to be the ETag received from the  previous request.

My suggestion is to look at a library that can do all this for you. [OkHttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) takes care of caching, so it will automatically send out the proper request headers for you.